# View No Results Behavior not working

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with [horses for sale](http://alanvelthuis.nl/nl/te-koop). I have [another view](http://alanvelthuis.nl/nl/verkocht) with a filter of `field_sold` = yes.

Currently there are no horses for sale. I want to add a `No Results Behavior` "Currently we have no horses for sale."

I tried in `Structure > View > Sold > Custom text (field) > NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR` but I don't see the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your view is not returning any results because of it's filter (field_sold = yes), if so, then no field are going to be shown in the view, so if you rewrite a field 'No results behavior' it won't show, simply because your view is not returning any row.

What you are looking for is the 'No results behavior' that's in the advanced tabs in the view. That's what is going to show when your view returns no results at all.

Just add Custom text field and put whatever you want there.

[image]